# security of the mining algorithms litecoin vs bitcoin - scrypt vs sha256?

Tags: proof-of-work, cryptography, sha256, scrypt

how is the cryptanalysis' current state on both sha256 and litecoin's scrypt?

is litecoin's scrypt on a security level like sha256?

by security i simply mean ways to "break"/"de-cipher" the hash functions in any way.

thanks

Comment: there has been no public evidence of a way to break either.